# WPF Shape bounding rectangle is always empty

Tags: wpf

I have the following code in my WPF application:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        p1 = new Point(50, 50);
        p2 = new Point(355, 50);
        p3 = new Point(50, 355);
        p4 = new Point(355, 355);

        Loaded += (x, y) => Draw();
        //ContentRendered += (x, y) => Draw();
    }
```

I create a Polygon shape and try to get its bounding rectangle *several ways*:

```
 private void Draw()
    {
        Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
        polygon.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        polygon.Points.Add(p1);
        polygon.Points.Add(p2);
        polygon.Points.Add(p3);
        polygon.Points.Add(p4);
        canvas.Children.Add(polygon);
        boundingRect = polygon.TransformToVisual(canvas).TransformBounds(new Rect(polygon.RenderSize));
        boundingRect = polygon.TransformToVisual(polygon).TransformBounds(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.LayoutInformation.GetLayoutSlot(polygon));
        boundingRect = polygon.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(polygon.RenderSize));
        boundingRect = GetRectOfObject(polygon);
        boundingRect = polygon.RenderedGeometry.Bounds;
    }

 private Rect GetRectOfObject(FrameworkElement _element)
    {
        Rect rectangleBounds = new Rect();
        rectangleBounds = _element.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, _element.ActualWidth, _element.ActualHeight));
        return rectangleBounds;
    }
```

**However, I always get {0;0;0;0}.**

On debug, I can see the points but its size is rendered 0:

[image]

How should I calculate the correct way?

Comment: You probably need to call [Measure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [Arrange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange(v=vs.110).aspx) on the rectangle to get it to render properly

Comment: You mean that I should _manually calculate_ the size of what the shape needs and _then_ I get the bounding size? As the shape will change dynamically, I can't tell the size of the needed space - that's what I expect from the WPF framework to calculate - instead of me. According to the lifecycle events, there is no more visual rendering after the loaded event, so basically the layout should be ready: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403418/Lifetime-events-of-a-WPF-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MSDN remarks of the [Measure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) method, calling `UpdateLayout` will obtain the necessary data (though it should be treated carefully), so this way the measuring works:

```
private void Draw()
{
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
    polygon.Points.Add(p1);
    polygon.Points.Add(p2);
    polygon.Points.Add(p3);
    polygon.Points.Add(p4);
    canvas.Children.Add(polygon);
    polygon.UpdateLayout();
    boundingRect = polygon.TransformToVisual(canvas).TransformBounds(new Rect(polygon.RenderSize));       
}
```

Thanks @ChrisF for the hints.